# How to do a custom alert

Tags: asp.net, messagebox

I'd like to know if is possible to make a custom `alert` maybe using `javascript` or `ajaxcontroltoolkit` I just need to know if is possible, if so I also would like to know HOW ?
The only way I've learned so far, is like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('MessageHere');", true);
```

But it's kind of ugly. And I saw the `popUp`of the `ConfirmButtonExtender` of `ajaxcontrolToolkit` and it's nice (But only useful on `buttons` when asking the confirmation. I don't know how to just send a message of `CONFIRMATION` you know ?  `confirming`
e.g: You Click on the button `register!` then you got the message `You registered the new user Sucessfuly`.

Comment: I take it you don't want to use a `<div>` / CSS?

Comment: It never came to my mind ... Is it a `good practice` ?  I have to confess that I've never saw this way. Is it hard? I'm new with `web programming`

Comment: We are talking about web pages here right?  And presumably you've already made one that has `<div>` tags in it.  So...submit the form, post to a page that says "you registered successfully"...

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few plugins for this; if you are already using JQuery, you can use the [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).  If you are using AJAX control toolkit, there is an extender to show/hide a DIV, called [the ModelPopupExtender](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co).  There are plenty of other components to find if you google "modal popup".  [This article](http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html) has a bunch of other alternatives too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try:

In your asp.net code-behind...

In your page load event...

```
IF some condition is met THEN
   me.pnl_success.visible = true
   ELSE me.pnl_success.visible = false
END IF
```

And then in your .aspx page, put an `<asp:panel>` in there with your success message in it.